# Bolzano-Weierstrass implies every uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an accumulation point

Tags: real-analysis

Let's suppose we have this version of BW theorem:

> **Theorem:** Every infinite bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an accumulation point.

Is there any way, using this (Or the every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence version) theorem, to prove that every uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has an accumulation point?

Does this generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Let $E\subset \mathbb R$ be uncountable. Then $E=\cup_{n=1}^\infty(E\cap [-n,n]).$

Comment: Since $E$ is uncountable, and a countable union of some sets $E\cap [-n,n]$, at least one of these sets is uncountable, and by construction bounded. Then I can apply BW. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's right.